# Detectron2 Alteranatives

Tags: computer-vision

Detectron2 is really good and it supports large number of models / but not all. Eg. Yolo.

Do we have alternative to detectron2 which provide easy to use API for both model inference and retraining? just like huggingface transformers for NLP.

Base library like keras/Tensorflow/torch are out of question as they are not API's rather whole framework for custom model development